# Lambda: A by-reference capture that could dangle

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, c++14

Scott Meyers, in Effective Modern C++, says, at lambda chapter, that:

Consider the following code:

```
void addDivisorFilter()
{
    auto calc1 = computeSomeValue1();
    auto calc2 = computeSomeValue2();

    auto divisor = computeDivisor(calc1, calc2);

    filters.emplace_back(
          [&](int value) { return value % divisor == 0; }
    );
}
```

> This code is a problem waiting to happen. The lambda refers to the local variable `divisor`, but that variable ceases to exist when `addDivisorFilter` returns. That's immediately after `filters.emplace_back` returns, so the function that's added to `filters` is essentially dead on arrival. Using that filter yields undefined behaviour from virtually the moment it's created.

The question is: Why is it an undefined behaviour? For what I understand, `filters.emplace_back` only returns after lambda expression is complete, and, during it execution, `divisor` is valid.

**Update**

An important data that I've missed to include is:

```
using FilterContainer = std::vector<std::function<bool(int)>>;
FilterContainer filters;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because the scope of the vector `filters` outlives the one of the function. At function exit, the vector `filters` still exists, and the captured reference to `divisor` is now dangling.

> For what I understand, filters.emplace_back only returns after lambda expression is complete, and, during it execution, divisor is valid.

That's not true. The vector stores the lambda created from the closure, and does not "execute" the lambda, you execute the lambda after the function exits. Technically the lambda is constructed from a closure (an compiler-dependent-named class) that uses a reference internally, like

```
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

struct _AnonymousClosure
{
    int& _divisor; // this is what the lambda captures
    bool operator()(int value) { return value % _divisor == 0; }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::function<bool(int)>> filters;
    // local scope
    {
        int divisor = 42;
        filters.emplace_back(_AnonymousClosure{divisor});
    }
    // UB here when using filters, as the reference to divisor dangle
}
```

Comment: Using the OP function example, If I define filters by `using FilterContainer = std::vector<bool>;` That reference could dangle?

Comment: @Amadeus If he store the `bool`, he wouldn't have to deal with dangling reference in the first place, as all the `std::vector` would contain were `true`/`false` values. But he stores `std::function` returning `bool` instead, and the return value depends on the divisor and he needs it to calculate the `bool` return value.

Comment: @Amadeus Make sure that whatever is stored in the vector does not store outlived references.

Answer (score 1):

You are not evaluating the lambda function while addDivisorFilter is active. You are simply adding "the function" to the collection, not knowing when it might be evaluated (possibly long after addDivisorFilter returned).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @vsoftco's answer, the following modified example code lets you experience the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

void addDivisorFilter(std::vector<std::function<int(int)>>& filters)
{
    int divisor = 5;

    filters.emplace_back(
          [&](int value) { return value % divisor == 0; }
    );
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::function<int(int)>> filters;
    addDivisorFilter(filters);
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << filters[0](10) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[live example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/7t74O8cLtS9pWYzP)

This example results in a `Floating point exception` at runtime, since the reference to `divisor` is not valid when the lambda is evaluated in `main`.

Comment: Oh, it is true. I've missed the part that he said `using FilterContainer = std::vector<std::function<int(int)>>`. I was thinking that it was: `using FilterContainer = std::vector<bool>`. Thanks, your answer was very elucidative